# Is there any way to overcome Attention Deficit Hyperactivity Disorder without using medicine?

Tags: mental-health, treatment, treatment-options, adhd

I have attention deficit hyperactivity disorder and want to be a web programmer. It's really annoying when you have an error and can't see where it is or can't focus.

I tried seeing a psychologist, but it didn't help that much.

What I want:

- I want to overcome it myself
- I want to get rid of it totally

I am aware that it will take time without professional help, but I don't know how to.

Comment: You can also get some advise from http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: On the programming aspect - unless every single software dev I have met has ADHD, being unable to spot the error is entirely unrelated. That's just how we are as humans. I mean, I cn rmv ll th vwls frm ths sntnce nd rdng wrks fn. Also msesnig up hte odrer dsoen't hrut etiher. It's just not very easy for our human eyes to find a needIe in a haystack

Comment: @Wayne Werner..I am aware of it..But it's related,you need to "follow a regular pattern" to find it..And that's the hard part for who have ADHD..

Comment: I have to force myself to focus when it comes time for that - looking character by character, etc. - You could also write some scripts to help you, if you find manual focusing too difficult

Comment: @Wayne Werner writting scripts makes sense,espacially with python..I will also check the links in your post..Thanks..Happy new year..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As aduckinthewinter mentioned, ADD/ADHD is not something that can be fixed - just managed. I wouldn't worry at all about trying to "fix" your ADD/ADHD, just understand it and work with it.

Some [experience hyperfocus](http://www.additudemag.com/adhd/article/612.html) if you do, learn to tap into it.

Also make sure that you're getting proper sleep and nutrition. You might try an [elimination diet](http://www.additudemag.com/adhd/article/859-4.html) to see if you have foods that trigger your inability to focus (you know, like sugar and caffeine).

Pay attention to your body - is there a time during the day that you have better focus? Morning? Night? Midday? Right after a nap? Does music help you focus? Distract you? Software development is actually a creative discipline - and while you do need to be able to focus when you're laying down code, there are a lot of times when you *need* creativity - even more so in the web sphere.

My personal philosophy is that our society (especially in America) is entirely too bent on making everyone "average". We are intolerant of behaviors and attitudes that stand out - unless of course they're at the head of a large organization or are really popular/entertaining. I think that causes a lot of problems with the mental health of a lot of people - in your case it seems like you feel broke and need fixing. In your words:

> I want to get rid of it totally

Why not embrace who you are? Learn what your strengths are and how to use them to your advantage. Learn what your weaknesses are and how trick them into working for you. Like maybe spending a ton of time answering questions on the StackExchange network ;)

Comment: ..You are totally right,actually i used it for my advantage..But sometimes espacially these days(it's winter) it goes worst..Nowadays i drink too much coffee,my doctor used to said don't drink it more than two,three cup of in a day..Because as a side effect now i have lack of sleep..Regular sleep routine > caffein..I will look for also elimination diet and experience hyperfocus..I think I must first fix my sleep pattern..

Answer (score 4):

In regards to your psychologist, remember that it often takes time before you find one that suits you. Perhaps this one simply isn't suitable?

Cognitive Behavior Therapy (CBT) is an effective non-drug treatment for ADHD. Ask your psychologist about it.

ADHD is postulated to relate to a "deficiency" of two chemicals within a particular region of the brain called the prefrontal cortex. Stimulant medications such as Ritalin boost the levels of these chemicals to within a "normal range". This is why medication is so effective. Perhaps you would consider medication?

I hate to sound harsh: ADHD is a neurodevelopment disorder. As such, ADHD cannot be "fixed", only managed.

**References**

1. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16961428, Mechanism of action of agents used in attention-deficit/hyperactivity disorder.

Comment: @ErenArdahan In that case, if your previous psychologist didn't work out, why not try a new one? Perhaps a new psychologist is all you need. It cannot hurt. May I ask why you would not consider medication?

Comment: Actually I stopped the treatment at CBT level of the treatment for some reasons a year ago..And additonally i don't have a high level of ADHD so ritalin was not that a good solution for me never used it..As i remember using a low-efficent antidepressan used-to solve my problem....And the main reason for me to go a psychologist was depression....My psychologist used to say CBT wiould fit me because I dont have a high level of a ADHD

Comment: Thanks for your help..Maybe i'm trying to find a solution in wrong place..As you mentioned it may be best for me to try new one..

Comment: Different doctors will have different opinions. Believe me when I say another doctor will prescribe you Ritalin. If Ritalin is not effective there are other options: amphetamine, atomoxetine, other antidepressants, etc.The fact that your doctor is not helping you with something that is clearly bothering you is ridicious. There are _so_ many medications you can try, you  _will_ find one that helps you. If your doctor won't help you then find another. In regards to the depression, again a psychologist and medication can help with both. Indeed: You should consult a doctor about this.

Comment: @michaelpri references added